# how to fix 'property or method is not defined' error in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Am passing an array props from a parent component to a child component
i can see the props array using vue-devtools passed successfully, but when i try to render with:

```
<template :v-for="(item, index) in messages_array">
```

i get:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "item" is not 
>   defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this 
>   property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based 
>   components, by initializing the property.

I want the `v-for` to iterate over the prop supplied.

- I've tried manually attaching the data into the component prop attribute directly

> Below are links to image of code...
>   tried pasting them here but couldnt format them properly.

[Single File component Recieving the prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8NAG.png)

[component Recieving the prop Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGPwV.png)

[The Parent Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiV0r.png)

[The Parent Component Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waykY.png)

Comment: Remove the colon. It should be `v-for`, not `:v-for`.

Comment: v-for is Directive and cannot be used as a binding type.

Comment: @Joel, did it resolve your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `v-for` instead of `:v-for` should resolve your issue:

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in messages_array">
```

Full documentation can be found here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for